# Class object list

Tags: c#, list, class, object

I have three classes, `person`, `address` and `phone`. A `person` can have multiple `address`es and each `address` has `phone` numbers. I need to serialize these classes and use it for web service call. Here how to initialize and assign values multiple `address` and `phone` number. Below is my class model.

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string dob { get; set; }
    public List<Address> address { get; set; }
    public Person()
    {
        this.address = new List<Address>();
    }
}

public class Address
{
    public string street { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string pobox { get; set; }
    public string postalcode { get; set; }
    public Phone phone { get; set; }
    public Address()
    {
        this.phone = new Phone();
    }
}

public class Phone
{    
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public string Landline { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: you just want to initialize a Person object?

Comment: Seems to be missing a question? What are you stuck on?

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
Person p = new Person(){
  Name = "PersonName",
  dob = "01-01-2015",
  addresses = new List<Address>(){
            new Address(){city = "New City",
                          pobox= "po box",
                          postalcode = "postal code",
                          street = "new street", 
                          phone = new Phone(){Landline = "landline",
                                                          Mobile="mobile"}},
            // new Address ...
    }
};
```

This should have been fairly simple. What did you not know?

Answer (score 0):

[**Fiddle Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QTl9a1)

```
var newPerson = new Person(){
                        Name="John",
                        dob = DateTime.Now.ToString(),
                        address = new List<Address>(){
                                            new Address(){street="str1",
                                                          city="etc",
                                                          phone = new Phone(){Mobile="999999"}}
                                                     }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to initialize such object is using [ObjectInitializers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx).

> Object initializers let you assign values to any accessible fields or
>   properties of an object at creation time without having to invoke a
>   constructor followed by lines of assignment statements. The object
>   initializer syntax enables you to specify arguments for a constructor
>   or omit the arguments (and parentheses syntax).

```
    var person = new Person
    {
        Name = "Name",
        dob = "dob",
        address = new List<Address>() { 
                        new Address{ 
                            city="city1", 
                            pobox = "pobox1", 
                            postalcode = "postalcode1", 
                            street = "street1", 
                            phone = new Phone{ Landline = "Landline1", Mobile = "Mobile1"}},

                        new Address{ 
                            city="city2", 
                            pobox = "pobox2", 
                            postalcode = "postalcode2", 
                            street = "street2", 
                            phone = new Phone{ Landline = "Landline2", Mobile = "Mobile2"}}
        }
    };
```